# Filling temporary table with SELECT * FROM function, within function in postgresql

Tags: database, postgresql, plpgsql

I am building function and I want it to use my another function, that returns table. I want to fill temporary table with result of this function and apparently this causes error. Code Below (function is under construction, so it is only part of code):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION energy.map_wit_messages_hourly()
RETURNS TABLE (_t_id text)

AS $$
BEGIN

   CREATE TEMP TABLE tmp_final ON COMMIT DROP AS
   SELECT * FROM map_wit_messages_hourly_for_specific_day('2017-09-02', 
   '2017-12-01 09:00:00', 'PL');

   RETURN QUERY 
   SELECT a._time_id FROM tmp_final a;

END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Does anyone knows solution of this problem?

Comment: Forgot to mention - running query without 'Create function (...)' works completely fine.

Comment: The temp table seems completely useless. Just return the result of the query.

Comment: This is only part of code, actually just example of my problem. 'map_wit_messages_hourly()' is going to be more complicated and temp tables will be necessary.

Comment: So what is the error you get?

Comment: plpqsql is quite new for me, I am using pgAdmin 4 and it doesn't give me error message. it just gives me message like: 'The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request.  Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application'.

Comment: I found out what's going on. I am already creating tmp_final in function that I want to call. I just had to change name of tmp_final.

Comment: Voting to close accordingly.